# issue while navigation method called from modal view in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

i have a problem while calling a navigation method from a presented modal view.
i have three view controllers, HomeViewController,loadViewController, modalViewController.

modalViewController presented as a moda view from HomeViewController by a button press. actually what i need is , when i press a button from presented modalViewController , modal view should be dismissed and the HomeViewController should navigate to loadViewController.
its not working with my code,

HomeViewController.m

```
  - (IBAction)shortCutButtonPressed:(id)sender {

         ShortCutViewController *viewController=[[ShortCutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

         [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

         [viewController release];
      }


   -(void)loadViewControllerLoad
     {
         loadViewController *loadView=[[loadViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:loadView animated:YES];

         [loadView release];

     }
```

modalViewController.m

//modal view controller will call the function loadViewControllerLoad from HomeViewController to navigate homeview to loadView. function call reaches correctly but the view is not navigating to loadView

```
    - (IBAction)HomeButtonPressed:(id)sender {

          homeView=[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

          [homeView loadViewControllerLoad];

          [[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

          [homeView release];

       }
```

function call reaches at HomeViewController but the view doesn't navigating to LoadView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see... your implementation is incorrect.When you are **allocating** your HomeViewController object in modalViewController.m , so the self.navigationController and all other properties of HomeViewController will be **nil** when calling loadViewControllerLoad method...So **Don't create a new object of  HomeViewController** . Get the object through any other way.. pass it or use propery  to get the HomeViewController object from your modalViewController to call the method "loadViewControllerLoad"

**Use .nib file Names to initialize your view instead of setting it to nil.**

```
ShortCutViewController *viewController=[[ShortCutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Your .nib name" bundle:nil];
```

**Example:**

```
ShortCutViewController *viewController=[[ShortCutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShortCutViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Apply this for loadViewController and HomeViewController too...

Comment: butStill also no change, its not navigating to loadView  :(

Comment: or mail me your sample application to shamsutk87@gmail.com ... i will check and correct after my lunch(just 30 min)....

Comment: okay thankyou for your solution, a simple line makes it works great [modal setParentClass:self];
and i removed the new homeView object, thanks